# 'sieh' vs 'siehe' in imperative

Tags: conjugation, imperative

Is there any difference between

> sieh dir das Video an

and

> siehe dir das Video an

?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Imperative with and without -e](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32655/imperative-with-and-without-e)

Answer (score 3):

Strong verbs that change *e* of the stem to *i* in the 2nd and 3d person singular present indicative form the imperative with *i* in the stem and no ending (https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/1275).

> geben – gib!
> nehmen – nimm!
> essen – iss!
> sehen – sieh!

In spoken language, some people do not change *e* to *i*, but forms such as *geb! nehm! ess! seh!* are heavily stigmatised (see for instance https://bastiansick.de/kolumnen/zwiebelfisch/fress-oder-sterbe/).

Then there is the present subjunctive, which has no vowel change and the ending *-e*: *gebe, nehme, esse, sehe*.

Therefore, **siehe dir das Video an!* is ungrammatical: strong verbs that change *e* to *i* in the stem cannot have an ending *-e* in the imperative, and present subjunctive forms (which have the ending *-e*) do not change the vowel of the stem. *Siehe* only exists (i) as a relic from biblical language (Luther has it where the Vulgata has *ecce*) and (ii) when giving references (where Latin would use *vide*).

Comment: Danke für die Klarstellung insbesondere hinsichtlich der Verben mit e>i-Vokalwechsel. Dennoch bleibt für mich die Frage, ob _‚siehe‘_ in Verweisen überhaupt ein Imperativ ist. Es könnte ein archaisierender Imperativ sein wie im biblischen „_und siehe! Der Engel des Herrn kam über sie_“, also ein formelhaft erstarrter Gebrauch. Damit würde ich von mir persönlich nicht bekannten Autoren jedoch quasi geduzt, kann das denn sein? Oder gibt es auch „ungerichtete“ Imperative, die sich nicht an ein _du_ oder _ihr_ oder _Sie_ wenden?: _Und siehe da: Wir wissen es nicht._

Comment: Jedenfalls scheint die Deutung als _Konjunktiv I_ falsch zu sein.

Answer (score 2):

**As far as the standard goes, both are fine and have the same meaning.**
Nevertheless, the more commonly used forms for the infinitive are those without "e", but how unusual the form with "e" sounds depends on the consonants the stem ends in. This ranges from "Atme" (which has no "e"-less form) over "Red(e)" where both are common, to "Sieh(e)", where "e"-less is common.

"Siehe" sounds quite formal and pompuous to me. Furthermore, the form "siehe" is fossilized as the "see" you use for references, as in "siehe Seite 11" (see p. 11), shortened to "s. S. 11".

*My personal* German would also use "seh" besides "sieh", but this form (using the stem when there is a e→i consonant change in present) is proscibed: There are quite a lot of people insisting on this being wrong.

Comment: Basically the '-e' is optional, and it's usually omitted except when required for pronunciation reasons as in 'atmen'. It makes sense that it would sound formal since people usually don't include optional syllables when speaking informally. I suppose "Gucke mal!" is impossible since it would be both formal and informal at the same time.

Comment: @RDBury 'gucke' does not sound wrong (but more common without 'e')